# push view controller based on value of UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel, switch-statement, uipickerview

I have a pickerview with 2 components, I have a 3 button segmented control.  Based on what the user selects between the pickerview and the segmented control, I have a UILabel that displays a string.  I would like to push a view controller based on what is displayed in the UILabel.  Should I use a switch statement for this? How do I convert the string values into integer expressions for the switch statement to work?

```
switch (fooLabel.text) {
    case @"foo-bar":
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:exampleVC animated:YES];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use multiple if statements

```
if ([fooLabel.text isEqualToString:@"foo-bar"])
{
    //Show one
}
else if ([fooLabel.text isEqualToString:@"bar-foo"])
{
    //Show Other
}
else
{
    //Show Default
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I can use "if" statements, but at this point it is possible that I might have upwards of 30 views to push to. So I was hoping to use switch statements for the ease of coding. It seems i need to create a dictionary to key from. By the time i do that, i could have the "if" statements coded. Thoughts?

Comment: I find it is easy enough to do the if statements. a dictionary would be a little more headache to maintain. I commonly use Constants rather than Strings so there is only one place to change the values.